Semantic commands in WYSIWYM editors like lyx
I've read that some professional mathematicians write in WYSIWYM editors like Lyx, because it's faster to edit the content, and the formatting can be done later.
I am thinking of using a WYSIWYM editor like this. However, I generally like to define "semantic commands". Is it still possible to define semantic commands in WYSIWM editors? e.g. to tell the editor "yes I wrote an 'x' here, but I want the underlying LaTeX to treat it as a different command than the 'x' I wrote 2 pages back". So that when I compile it to latex I get \newcommand{\xversion1}{x} and \newcommand{\xversion2}{x} where \xversion1 is used on the first page and \xversion2 on the latter page.

Yes. It is called adding content to the layout of the lyx document. Look at the LyX's Customization manual, section 5.3.7, "Paragraph styles".

but you cannot implement the actual code you gave as an example because you cannot use a numeral in the name of a control sequence. (this is nothing to do with how you edit, though.)

The problem of LyX customization is the cost/benefit. Too complex and tedious for a few uses. How often are you going to use  the versions of \xversion? You can also include raw latex commands in the preamble (e.g.  \newcommand\xversion{foo}) and anywhere in body of the document  (e.g. \xversion\renewcommand\xversion{bah}\xversion) without any customization. The only problem is understand that LyX is completely agnostic about what you include this way, it is up to you that  the code is compatible with the LyX export to LaTeX.
